# Save iText created PDF to internal memory as MODE_WORLD_READABLE

Tags: android, itext

The file is generating fine. I decided to add some logic to handle if the device didn't have an external storage, or if the external storage was set to read-only; in which case, I would try to save the file to a specific directory in my app's filesystem. This works fine, too. The problem is when trying to get the third party app to show the file. I understand that I should be saving the file as Mode_World_Readable, but just can't get it to work from the examples I have found.

Here is an excerpt of my code:

```
//Build a filename from the data provided
String reportTitle = args.getFromDate() + "_" + args.getToDate() + ".pdf";

: : : :
: : : :

} else {
   //Something else is wrong. 
   //Maybe there isn't a SD Card
   //It may be one of many other states, but all we need
   //to know is we can neither read nor write to external storage
   mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
   try {

      //Get the absolute path to the filesystem directory 
      //where the internal files are saved. 
      File painReportFolder = ctx.getFilesDir();
      //The string of the sub directory we want to access
      String filename = "Reports/PainReports/";
      //Create a new 'file' to build the directory
      File file = new File(painReportFolder, filename);
      //Make the directory if it doesn't exist
      file.mkdirs();

      //Build a FileOutputStream with the filename appended
      theFile = new FileOutputStream(file + java.io.File.separator + reportTitle);

      //This is what the examples suggest,
      //But it doesn't work.
      //In this configuration, at least
      //FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

: : : :
: : : :

// creation of the different writers
PdfWriter writer;
if(mExternalStorageAvailable == false &&  mExternalStorageWriteable == false){
   //if no sd card, or sd card is read-only,
   //write to specific directory in internal
   writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, theFile );
}else{
   //otherwise, write to a dir on the sd card
   writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(currentDirectory + java.io.File.separator + reportTitle));
}
```

So PdfWriter.getInstance() will accept a FileOutputStream, but it wont accept the FileOutputStream created by openFileOutput and I can't add MODE_WORLD_READABLE to 'theFile'

I've been researching this for the past week, and trying out different variations of code. Nothing I've found on Stackoverflow or anywhere else directly answers my query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know why this was downvoted, or by whom (probably some troll, as no comment was left), but further research has shown to me that there is no solution.

Why?

Take out your sd card and try to take a photo; it says that it needs a card - it wont save to internal; and this is a bundled app.

So I've rolled-back all of my sd checking code:

If there is sd; save

If there is sd, but it is read-only; show error page

If there is no sd; show error page